# Listing all topics in AWS-IoT to isolate rogue topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

Is there a way to list all the topics that the MQTT Clients are sending data to or receiving data from in AWS-IoT?

1. I didn't come across this anywhere in the documentation or the console.
2. What if a client device gets hacked, and the exploiter starts making his own topics and uses it as a network for himself? right now, is there a way to track rogue topics and kick the device out?

If I know there is an unauthorized topic i can detect it, but for that i still need a list of topics like we get in RabbitMQ.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no managed way to list all topics.

But there is a way to block the client/s from sending data to other "Rogue" topics as well as subscribing to their own topics.

The answer is to make a policy for that device on the server-side (IoT Console or CLI) to send data only to authorized topics. Once the policy is implemented, the client cannot publish data to any other topics.

Reference :http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/authorization.html